# How can I make a bunch of divs stack in a grid within their parent?

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to make a 2 row scrollable interface. I found I'm really bad at explaining it, but here is what it should look like. http://valeness.tk

The problem comes when I add more item elements, they break the height boundary and start to stack into 3 rows. I would like it to stay 2 rows and use the overflow-x: scroll property so it can scroll left and right.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Accomadere Vive</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="top">
<div class="top-left">
<a href="#" class="nav" id="active">HOME</a>
<a href="#" class="nav" id="inactive">ABOUT ME</a>
<a href="#" class="nav" id="inactive">PROJECTS</a>
<a href="#" class="nav" id="inactive">BLOG</a>
</div>
<div class="top-right">
<div class="prof">James Horton</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="main">

<div class="item-container">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</HTML>
```

CSS

```
body
{
background-color: #090909;
}

div.top
{
width: 99%;
height: 110px;
padding: 5px;
/*border: 1px solid blue;*/
}

div.top-left
{
position: relative;
height: 100px;
width: 40%;
left: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
/*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

div.prof
{
position: relative;
height: 30px;
width: 150px;
line-height: 30px;
text-indent: 5px;
font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
color: #00ff00;
background-color: #111111;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: italic;
}

div.prof:after
{
content: '';
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
margin-left: -150px;
background-image: url('avatar.png');
background-size: 30px 30px;
background-color: #111111;
border-left: 4px solid #00ff00;
}

div.top-right
{
position: relative;
float: right;
height: 100px;
width: 40%;
right: 5px;
margin-top: -107px;
/*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

a#active.nav
{
font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
color: #00ff00;
font-size: 18px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}

a#inactive.nav
{
font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
color: #999999;
font-size: 18px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
-o-transition: all .5s;
-moz-transition: all .5s;
-webkit-transition: all .5s;
transition: all .5s;
}

a#inactive.nav:hover
{
font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 18px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
-o-transition: all .5s;
-moz-transition: all .5s;
-webkit-transition: all .5s;
transition: all .5s;
}

div.main
{
display: block;
position: absolute;
height: 74%;
width: 96%;
padding: 15px;
border: 1px solid green;
}

div.item-container
{
width: 85%;
height: 400px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border: 1px solid blue;
}

div.item
{
width: 300px;
height: 170px;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-top: 15px;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
background-color: #202020;
float: left;
}
```

The elements in question are div.item and div.item-container.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why do you want it to stay as 2 rows and scroll left-right? I feel that having to scroll in two directions to see all the content is a little annoying.

Comment: Also, you are using `@id` attributes incorrectly, they should be unique, but you have three elements with "inactive" ids. Should they be classes?

Comment: Lego Stormtroopr: They won't contain any real "content" but instead will act as a feed full of both internal and external links. It would be similar to browsing a news feed or blog. Also, there shouldn't be any vertical scrolling alongside horizontal unless your monitor is too small.

And I didn't think about that. They could be classes, don't know why I made them ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following fiddle which should have it fixed:
http://jsfiddle.net/pbEgp/1/

It was solved by adding the following:

```
display: inline-block;
```

and removing

```
float: left;
```

on the item class, then adding this for the container:

```
overflow-x: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
```

It is also worth noting that you would either have to wrap the div's in rows or separate the rows by a break as in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at making a visual table, then I'd recommend using [CSS tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Tables). Unlike HTML tables, they are purely visual, however you need to have the appropriate HTML structure. If you need these to be viewed as a table, I suggest there is some semantic meaning beyond a simple set of `div`s. Maybe its two different lists - so you could semantically mark them up as `ul`s and then apply the table styling.

To accomodate the changes to get this working, I've made a view changes which you can [see in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Fpwj/).

However, the gist of it is adding another layer into the HTML to capture the "rows":

```
<div class="item-container">
    <div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>

    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then styling each of these:

```
.item-container > * {
    display:table-row;
}

div.item-container
{
    /* Identical attributes ignored */
    display: table;
}
```

There were a few big changes to the `div.item` to have it style the same, including adding border styling (table cells don't have margins) and adding a minimum width, otherwise the cells shrunk with the table.

```
div.item
{
    min-width:300px;
    border:15px solid #090909;
    background-color: #202020;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Then lastly, adding the right `overflow` to the right element (I'll let you pick where this should go, but in the fiddle its on `div.main`:

```
overflow:auto;
```

Comment: I didn't use this particular solution this time. But your answer has been added to my learning resources as you taught me some things I didn't know.